# Show Multiple Result Tuples into One Tuple in Different Different Columns

Tags: mysql

Original Database Schema--

```
   id      username     date         Grade     
    ----------------------------------------
    1     Haryana   15/02/2001         A        
    2     Haryana   20/02/2008         B+    
    3     Punjab    15/05/2001         A    
    4     Haryana   25/02/2008         A    
    5     Punjab    25/02/2008         B+
```

Required Output With Selection Query--

```
 username     date     Grade   username  date     Grade   username     date     Grade
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    haryana   15/02/2001   A     Haryana 20/02/2008   B+     Haryana   25/02/2008    A     
     Punjab    15/05/2001  A     Punjab  25/02/2008   B+
```

**Note->**
*Basically I want column name "username" to be used for Making Multiple rows of user "Haryana" to be into Single Tuple With Multiple Rows with Multiple Columns..*

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in your presentation layer/application level code, if such a thing is available; it's generally faster and much more (and more easily) scalable and flexible. Otherwise, see pivot queries.

Comment: Basically PHP Don't Have that Much Possibilities :)

Comment: I don't understand that comment :-$

Comment: Like i am Saying i just Wanna Format Data on Basis of "username" Column. like above

Comment: And You are Using Some Rank and @prev whic was not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

Relational database software is terrible at creating result sets (tables) in which the number or names of columns is dependent on the *data* in other tables. That's what you are asking for. It's difficult code to write and practically impossible to maintain. Even if you get it to work in SQL, it will be a miserable hack™. The person who works on it after you will curse you.

This sort of thing, often called a *pivot*, is best done in database client software.

That being said, perhaps you can try the [`GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregation function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Here's a possible query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', username,date, Grade) ORDER BY date SEPARATOR ' | ')
  FROM table
 GROUP BY username
```

It will give a result set like this:

```
Haryana 15/02/2001 A | Haryana 20/02/2008 B+ | Haryana 25/02/2008 A
Punjab 15/05/2001 A | Punjab 25/02/2008 B+
```

A small amount of string processing in php or any other language can transform this kind of result to present the illusion that it is in a table.

Comment: Sir,i want each column to have its own like you concatenated the each tuple to one Column..Is there is any thing which i can do to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution (see Ollie's first sentence, or my comment above). So, just for fun...

```
SELECT username
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN date END) date1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN grade END) grade1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN date END) date2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN grade END) grade2 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN date END) date3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN grade END) grade3 
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = username THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=username 
         FROM my_table x
            ,(SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY username
            , date
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY username;
```

Comment: But i am Not Supposed to do this,basically i want formatting of data by returning it in single row for common Column Value that's it.Its Just a Sample table....

Comment: Look, it is **extremely unwise** to attempt to do what you want in SQL.   It's a miserable hack. You need to do it in Php, or C#, or Crystal Reports, or whatever client package you have available.